# Do 11 type selectors override class selector?

Tags: css

A class selector has specificity of 10. If I'm going to compose a selector of 11 html type selectors will that override class selector?

```
.some {color: green}
div div div div div div div div div div div {color: red}
```

What color will be applied?

And do 101 class selectors override id selector?

PS. Surely I can experiment myself with class overriding type selectors, but it's tiresome to do the same with id selector.

Comment: EXPLAIN, what you're saying

Comment: @Tushar, added example

Comment: [See Yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u6odb08v/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be a misunderstanding of "specificity 10" on your question -- that is not '9+1', it's a whole different thing, more like a list "0 ids, 1 class, 0 tags", and you can have "0 ids, 0 classes, 11 tags" and it doesn't change the fact you still don't as much power as a single class.

So, writing it more clearly, you'd have (0,1,0) and (0,0,11), etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the `10` specificity for `.some` is higher than `11` in that multiple selectors...

That's because the `class` has higher specificity than selector.
So the "test" text will be **green**.

Example:

```
------------------------------------------------
|Inline |       |   Classes,   |   Elements    |
|styles |  IDs  |attributes and|     and       |
|       |       |pseudo-classes|pseudo-elements|
------------------------------------------------

.some {color:green}
------------------------------------------------
|   0   |   0   |      1       |       0       |
------------------------------------------------
div div div div div div div div div div div {color:red }
------------------------------------------------
|   0   |   0   |      0       |      11       |
------------------------------------------------
div div div div div div div div div div div.some {color:blue }
------------------------------------------------
|   0   |   0   |      1       |      11       |
------------------------------------------------
```

So in brief....
`0-0-1-11` is higher than `0-0-1-0` and this is higher than `0-0-0-11`

```css
.some {
  color: green
}
div div div div div div div div div div div {
  color: red
}
div div div div div div div div div div div.txt {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="some">
                      test
                    </div>
                    <div class="txt">
                      test
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you shouldn't read that specificity as 10.

> You can generally read the values as if they were just a number, like 1,0,0,0 is "1000", and so clearly wins over a specificity of 0,1,0,0 or "100". The commas are there to remind us that this isn't really a "base 10" system, in that you could technically have a specificity value of like 0,1,13,4 - and that "13" doesn't spill over like a base 10 system would.

.

> CSS applies vastly different specificity weights to classes and IDs. In fact, an ID has infinitely more specificity value! That is, no amount of classes alone can outweigh an ID.

[See this article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)